# gatsby/netlify CMS - javascript heap out of memory

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

Gatsby and Netlify CMS were running nicely for a while but now it fails when trying to run `gatsby develop`. With a "JavaScript heap out of memory" error.

Every npm is updated and I've tried `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` that some GitHub issue threads mention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You hit the nail with the command to fix it:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

However, adding the previous script in the terminal will fix it locally, it may work if your `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` fails but not in the server.

To fix it there in the server (Netlify side), you need to reach to the `nettlify-cli`. The easiest way to do it is by adding a file named `netlify.toml` in the root of your project with the following content.

```
[build.environment]
  NODE_OPTIONS = "--max_old_space_size=4096"
```

Basically you are setting the Node options when Netlify builds the site exactly in the same way you did it in the terminal.

The issue comes from the Node side; it seems that the extra transpiling being done is just now making Node hit its default limit without increasing it automatically.

If you need more information about the `netlify.toml` file check out the [File-based configuration documentation of Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/).

Comment: Thanks a million mate, this is exactly what I needed for a site of mine that was getting huge, you saved my day. I'll definitely check the Netlify's file-based configuration documentation link that you provided. ^   ^